# Get an access to MongoDB attribute?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am writing a query to get total sum of elements in array inside document, and I'm getting correct result, but how can I simply get and access to "total_sum" (which is 6034 here) in order to make further calculations?
Also, I'm doing in in Mongo Shell, but I am struggling with correct syntax in PyMongo. If you can help me, I'll appreciate it very much.

```
   db.reportsColl.aggregate([
            {$unwind: '$conditions'},
        {$group: {_id: '$_id', 'sum': { $sum: 1}}},
        {$group: {_id: null, total_sum: {'$sum': '$sum'}}}
        ])
```

> > > { "_id" : null, "total_sum" : 6034 }

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "get access to"? Do you mean read the value from the dict? Did you realize the output is inside an array? Also you simply needed `db.reportsColl.aggregate([{ "$unwind": "$conditions" },{ "$group": { "_id": null, "total_sum": { "$sum": 1 } }})` here. The other `$group` in the middle isn't really doing anything since `_id` is "unique".

Comment: Yes, correct, I need to read the value from the dict. And your solution doesn't return anything. But thanks for pointing that output inside is an array.